# Displaying two sections of specific size in a table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to fill a table view with an array, but I want two sections, and in the first section I want to display the imformation from `indexpath.row == 0` to   `indexpath.row == 4` and in the second section the information from `indexpath.row == 5` to  `indexpath.row == 9`. How can I do that? I have this code for the second section:

```
 if (indexPath.section == 1){
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";
        static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";
        int nodeCount = [self.entries count];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        if (nodeCount > 0)
        {
            if (indexPath.row > 4) {

                AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.textLabel.text = appRecord.artist;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = appRecord.appName;
                if (!appRecord.appIcon)
                {
                    if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
                    {
                        [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    }
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];               
                }
                else
                {
                    UIImage *image = appRecord.appIcon;
                    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(83.0, 48.0);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
                    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 83.0, 48.0);
                    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
                    appRecord.appIcon = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    cell.imageView.image = appRecord.appIcon;    
                }


        }
        return cell;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the number of section in this function

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 2;
}
```

Perhaps you also want to implement

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"section title";
}
```

set the number of lines in the following function

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 5; // since you have 0-4 and 5-9 for the two sections
}
```

after seeing in your code [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
I assumed self.entries is the one array that you have been talking about.
You can initialize the UITableViewCell property in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

by using a combination of section and row to get the index of your self.entries, probably something like

```
AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5*indexPath.section];
```

I hope i got your question right.